# Horizontal menu vertically and horizontally aligned with mouseover effect, how to create a crossbrowser solution?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an horizontal menu, vertically and horizontally aligned.

I'm actually using

  tags, and it looks exactly as I want in firefox.
  However, this is the only browser where it is rendered correctly.

- In internet explorer 9, the background that appears when I mouse over on an item, is moved 1 px upper, over the black line.
- In chrome, the li element is 20px high instead of 16 like on firefox, moving the menu a little lower
- In safari and opera I have the same chrome problem.

Notice that opera, safari and chrome also have a problem where my separator is 3px high and 1px large, while on firefox I can visualize it correctly.

I don't know really why, but because I lost 2 nights behind this problem I think I need definitely some help.

Here is the situation with firefox (you can click on images to zoom in):

[image: Firefox situation]

While here you can see Chrome situation (webkit in general):

[image: Webkit situation]

The **css** for the menu is this:

```
#menu
{
  bottom: 111px;
  height:  54px;
  width:   100%;
  top:     auto;
}

#menu-bar-top, #menu nav
{
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  width:              inherit;
}

#menu-bar-top
{
  background-image:  url(../../img/Layouts/default/Hr-bottom.png);
  background-color:                                   transparent;
  border-style:                                              none;
  height:                                                    18px;
}

#menu nav
{
  background-image:  url(../../img/Layouts/default/Menu-background.png);
  height:                                                          36px;

}

#menu nav div
{
  text-align:  center;
  height:     inherit;
  margin:           0;
}

#menu nav ul
{
  list-style-type:         none;
  font-family:     Ethnocentric;
  font-size:              1.2em;
  padding:                    0;
  height:               inherit;
  margin:                     0;
  color:                  white;
}

#menu nav ul li
{
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  display:     inline;
  padding:          0;
  margin:           0;
}

#menu nav ul li.menu-separator
{
  background-position:                                     center center;
  background-repeat:                                           no-repeat;
  background-image:    url(../../img/Layouts/default/Menu-separator.png);
  font-size:                                                         1px;
}

#menu nav ul li a
{
  text-decoration:  none;
  padding:          10px 10px 8px 10px;
  margin:         0 -5px;
  color:           white;
}

#menu nav ul li a:hover
{
  background-position:                                                  0px 0px;
  background-repeat:                                                   repeat-x;
  background-image:    url(../../img/Layouts/default/Menu-background-hover-2.png);
}
```

While **html** can be found here:

```
<section id="menu">
    <hr id="menu-bar-top" />
    <nav>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="menu-separator">&nbsp;</li>
                <li><a href="#">Lavori svolti</a></li>
                <li class="menu-separator">&nbsp;</li>
                <li><a href="#">Balbo e consorzi</a></li>
                <li class="menu-separator">&nbsp;</li>
                <li><a href="#">Ciao</a></li>
                <li class="menu-separator">&nbsp;</li>
                <li><a href="#">Etc...</a></li>
                <li class="menu-separator">&nbsp;</li>
                <li><a href="#">Etc...</a></li>
                <li class="menu-separator">&nbsp;</li>
                <li><a href="#">Etc...</a></li>
                <!-- ... other Etcs ...-->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</section>
```

Because I think **ul** is creating me more problems than it should, I'm ok with changing html markup (notice that is html5), doesn't matter if it feels a bit incorrect (like using divs and spans only). What I really need, is a crossbrowser solution to this and any suggestion is appreciated. I don't need Ie6 support, I'm ok with IE9 and lasterversion of chrome, opera, safari, firefox.

Notice that the background of my menu and the background of the mouseover effect are both gradients, so I can't just use a color.

Thanks for any suggestion, hope anyone can help me with this because I can't really solve the problem and I would like to avoid various css per browser.

**Edit 1:**
I don't get why I can't make the separator height what I want, I put text inside but definitely doesn't fit the size I need, it's an inline element but I can't put a block element inside an inline element :\

**Edit 2:**
Ok I have uploaded the whole webpage with graphics, I didn't create a JSFiddle at the moment but you can see the webpage and download it as a ZIP file:

[View the webpage](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/762638/Files/Documents/Work/Setin/webpage/index.html)

[Download the webpage](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/762638/Files/Documents/Work/Setin/SetinHomepage.zip) (if you don't trust me simply download the otherone from the browser)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FireDragonDoL/R5nuk/6/)

**Edit 3:**
Added the JS Fiddle, however I can't make font works there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Jona's answer helped me a lot with pseudo-elements (I didn't know it was possible such a thing), it doesn't answer completely to my question: expecially, I used a line-height that is **half** of my height and I didn't use float: left, which instead creates only problems with centering the menu.

Instead what really fixed everything for me is display:block on A tag and expecially display: inline-block for li tags.

This changed the way tags behaves to do exactly what I wanted with some minor tweaks.

I still have some small problems with google chrome, but I think is connected with the fact that for chrome (and safari) the font is 20 px height instead of 16 like in all other browsers (don't know why), but they are not so bad (the text is 4 px lowered, I can accept this).

Here is the complete edit of what I built with css, using Diodeus's and Jona's answers, along with a small html markup change:

**HTML:**

```
  <section id="menu">
    <hr id="menu-bar-top" />
    <nav>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lavori svolti</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Balbo e consorzi</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ciao</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Etc...</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Etc...</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </section>
```

**CSS:**

```
/**
 *     Creates a font that should be used in all pages TEST
 */

@font-face
{
  font-family:                                                          Ethnocentric;
  src:                                              url('../files/ethnocentric.eot');
  src:         url('../../files/ethnocentric.eot?iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                                 url('../../files/ethnocentric.woff') format('woff'),
                              url('../../files/ethnocentric.ttf') format('truetype'),
                                   url('../../files/ethnocentric.svg') format('svg');
}

*
{
  padding: 0;
  margin:  0;
}

html, body
{
  max-height:               100%;
  overflow:               hidden;
  height:                   100%;
}

/**
 *     Change the basic background color of the page
 */
html
{
  background-image: url(../../img/Layouts/default/Background.png);
  font-family:                                  Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:                                                 10px;
}

/**
 *     Helper to clear from float
 */
.clear
{
  clear: both;
}

input[type="radio"].radio-hidden
{
  position: absolute;
  display:      none;
  left:      -9999px;
  top:       -9999px;
}

header, #menu, footer
{
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  position:          absolute;
  overflow:            hidden;
  bottom:                   0;
  width:                 100%;
  right:                    0;
  left:                     0;
  top:                      0;
}
header
{
  background-image: url(../../img/Layouts/default/Gradient-top.png);
  height:                                                     125px;
}

#content
{
  /*background-repeat:                                             repeat-y;
  background-image:  url(../../img/Layouts/default/Background-center.png);*/
  position:                                                         fixed;
  overflow:                                                          auto;
  margin:                                                   0 auto 0 auto;
  bottom:                                                           165px;
  /*width:                                                            789px;*/
  width: 77%;
  right:                                                                0;
  left:                                                                 0;
  top:                                                              112px;

  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  background-color: #5E656A;
}

#menu
{
  bottom: 111px;
  height:  54px;
  width:   100%;
  top:     auto;
}

footer
{
  background-image: url(../../img/Layouts/default/Gradient-bottom.png);
  height:                                                        111px;
  top:                                                            auto;
}

header div
{
  margin-right:  auto;
  margin-left:   auto;
  padding-top:   16px;
  width:        788px;
}

#menu-bar-top, #menu nav
{
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  width:              inherit;
}

#menu-bar-top
{
  background-image:  url(../../img/Layouts/default/Hr-bottom.png);
  background-color:                                   transparent;
  border-style:                                              none;
  height:                                                    18px;
}

#menu nav
{
  background-image:  url(../../img/Layouts/default/Menu-background.png);
  height:                                                          36px;

}

#menu nav div
{
  text-align:  center;
  height:     inherit;
  margin:           0;
}

#menu nav ul
{
  list-style-type:         none;
  font-family:     Ethnocentric;
  font-size:              1.2em;
  padding:                    0;
  height:               inherit;
  margin:                     0;
  color:                  white;
}

#menu nav ul li
{
  position:     relative;
  display:  inline-block;
  padding:             0;
  height:        inherit;
  margin:              0;
  top:               0px;
}

#menu nav ul li a
{
  text-decoration:         none;
  line-height:             15px;
  display:                block;
  padding:                 10px;
  margin:          0 -2px 0 1px;
  color:                  white;
}

#menu nav ul li a:hover, #menu nav ul li a:focus
{
  background-position:                                                    0px 0px;
  background-repeat:                                                     repeat-x;
  background-image:    url(../../img/Layouts/default/Menu-background-hover-2.png);
}

#menu nav ul li a:before
{
  background-image: url(../../img/Layouts/default/Menu-separator.png);
  position:                                                  absolute;
  content:                                                         "";
  bottom:                                                       33.3%;
  width:                                                          2px;
  left:                                                          -2px; /* negative width of the seperator */
  top:                                                          33.3%;
}

#menu nav ul li a.menu-first:before
{
  background: none;
  width:         0;
  left:          0;
}

/* reset the firsit item */
#menu nav ul li:first-child a
{
    margin-left: -1px;
}

#menu nav ul li:first-child a:before
{
    display: none;
}

#company-info, #webdesigner-info
{
  font-size:    0.9em;
  position:  absolute;
  color:      #8E8C8C;
}

#company-info
{
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-top:  11px;
  left:           0;
  top:            0;
}

#webdesigner-info
{
  margin-bottom: 11px;
  margin-right:  16px;
  bottom:           0;
  right:            0;
}
```

You can visit the webpage [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/762638/Files/Documents/Work/Setin/webpage_test/index.html) (this link won't last ever)

Comment: It's not really a good idea to post temporal, short-lived links... see if you can host it somewhere more permanent, create a test case, or just put up a screenshot like you did with your question.

Comment: I put the code of what is changed in the answer, the screenshot on how it looks now can be seen in the main question because firefox shown it correctly so it's useless. I put for those who answered to the question, but definitely that's not for future uses.

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:block` on your `A`-tag. Move your menu separator to the A-tag.

Change your LI to "inline-block":

```
#menu nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

There may be a few more things to tweak. Without the full URL to your images it's hard to mock this up remotely.

Comment: How to move the menu separator to my a tag? I mean, it's an image. I'm preparing material with images and current html + css, give me a bit

Answer (score 1):

I made a small demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3bydX/

I `float`ed the `li` element to get in them in one row, the die `a` elements have `line-height` equally to their `height` so the text is vertically centered.

Since you're okay with changing the markup, I removed the seperator `li`s and used pseude elements to achieve this effect. This way you also get rid of the non semantic markup.

Comment: Ok let me test on my webpage, I updated the question with images/webpage/jsfiddle

Comment: How do you center horizontally in the page the menu with float: left ?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could code an example in JSFiddle, but I would start with adding float left to the li tag.  This should fix your cross browser issues. Along with other tweaks

```
#menu nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

  /* Add this */
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: I'm preparing a JSFiddle example with it. How can I handle images with it? I'm preparing material as stated in the other comment, give me a bit.

Comment: I did it and images are working well, however I have problems with the custom font (see the edit).

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL So basically it functions for me in both Safari and Chrome if you remove the following line:  font-size: 1px; from the menu separator class.  I tested it using the files you uploaded to your drop box.

Comment: If I put float: left, how do you center the menu horizontally?